# What is the most efficient way to complete A Paragon of Her Kind in Dragon Age: Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I have a copy of Dragon Age: Origins Ultimate Edition and am just about to start the quest for the Dwarves.

I'm trying for a 1.5 playthrough for all the trophies/achievements, which means saves at certain points during the story. The others have been easy, but since this main quest actually seems to contain 4 trophies/achievements, and since I actually picked up Shale (from The Stone Prisoner DLC), I want to make sure I get it right.

Given that I have Shale in my party, what's the most efficient way to complete A Paragon of Her Kind, keeping in mind that I also wish to complete A Golem's Memories (Stone's Lament DLC trophy/achievement)? Note that removing Shale from my party *is* an option, although I obviously can't un-recruit her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to save your game right before you enter the Anvil of the Void room.

You will also need Shale in your party.

During the conversation options you'll have to either choose to side Branka or Caridin.

> If you choose to side with Branka and save the Anvil you will need to kill Shale, which will stop you from completing "A Golem's memories". So save before you enter the room, pick one option, fight through the resulting in one achievement, then do the other. I would suggest that you choose to side with Branka first, killing both Caridin and Shale, then loading and continuing on since the subsequent unlocking of "A Golem's Memories" requires a trip back to camp, conversation options with Shale, and then a trip to the new area they unlock.

Comment: Worked beautifully. The only thing to note is that for the second group of two you can save before you leave the Anvil of the Void room. In fact, you should, as you'll immediately (after cut scenes) make a choice.